# How to access an object without knowing its name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem. I want to get my service values on an angular front-end but this time I can't do that because I don't know the name of the service object (the name is the comm key soo it is variable).

The service response looks like:

```
11791146: {m_serverQuery: {…}, m_key: 11791146}
```

I need to get `m_key` here - notice that `11791146` is variable.

I've tried:

```js
console.log(data);
let arr = data[0].m_key;
console.log(arr);
```

and

```js
console.log(data);
let arr = data[m_key];
console.log(arr);
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `data[11791146].m_key`?

Comment: Can't cause that number "11791146" increment every time I called to service so it is variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (also [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)) to get keys (or values) of an object without any knowledge of it's data.

Try the following

```js
let data = { 11791146: {m_serverQuery: {name: 'sample'}, m_key: 11791146}};

console.log(Object.keys(data)[0]);

console.log(Object.values(data)[0]);
console.log(Object.values(data)[0].m_serverQuery);
console.log(Object.values(data)[0].m_key);
```

Note: In both cases, I assume the object `data` has only one property. So I access it directly using `[0]`. If not you will have to take care of multiple elements in the array returned by the functions.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can do that generically.

```js
var response = {
  11791146: {m_serverQuery: "", m_key: 11791146} 
}

var mKey = response[Object.keys(response)[0]].m_key;
console.log(mKey);
```

If there will be multiple keys, you can loop through using `Object.keys(response)` and get all the keys in an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Object.keys to recieve m_key like that:

```
const key = Object.keys(data);
const m_key = data[key[0]];
```